# How to get coordinates of border meeting points from scipy.spatial.Voronoi

Tags: python, scipy, voronoi, scipy-spatial

I'm using scipy.spatial.Voronoi to calculating Voronoi diagram:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi

points = np.array([[51.129378, 17.02925 ],
                   [51.086225, 17.012689],
                   [50.913433, 15.765608],
                   [53.121764, 17.987906],
                   [53.134083, 17.995708],
                   [51.75805 , 19.529786]])


vor = Voronoi(points)
```

I receive following diagram form it:

[image: Voronoi diagram]

**How to get coordinates of orange points?** It seems that there is no (at least documented) attribute for it.

Motivation: My goal is to calculate biggest circle without blue points. So I'm planning to calculate distances between each orange and blue points. Then I will check each orange point and pick one which will have highest minimal distance value. It will be center of my target circle. Maybe there is other way to do that without Voronoi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those points are available in the `vertices` attribute. The [documentation of Voronoi](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html) describes the `vertices` attribute as "Coordinates of the Voronoi vertices." (Scroll down in the linked web page to find the descriptions of the attributes.)

Here's your example:

```
In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: from scipy.spatial import Voronoi

In [7]: points = np.array([[51.129378, 17.02925 ],
   ...:                    [51.086225, 17.012689],
   ...:                    [50.913433, 15.765608],
   ...:                    [53.121764, 17.987906],
   ...:                    [53.134083, 17.995708],
   ...:                    [51.75805 , 19.529786]])
   ...:                    

In [8]: vor = Voronoi(points)
```

These are the points that are plotted as the orange dots:

```
In [9]: vor.vertices
Out[9]: 
array([[52.56952748, 18.87348869],
       [51.7974129 , 18.19059283],
       [56.91850562, 12.00665177],
       [52.80703622, 16.09228084],
       [50.53735155, 18.50739102],
       [51.36995954, 16.33786426]])
```

Note that `voronoi_plot_2d(vor)` chooses x and y limits on the plot that are too small to see all the vertices.  Here's a plot that shows them all:

```
In [15]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [16]: from scipy.spatial import voronoi_plot_2d

In [17]: voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
Out[17]: <Figure size 1280x960 with 1 Axes>

In [18]: plt.xlim(50, 58)
Out[18]: (50, 58)

In [19]: plt.ylim(11, 20)
Out[19]: (11, 20)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This is quite embarrassing for me. It looks like i wrongly translated vertices in my mind. But trimmed plot also added some confusion. Thanks for showing how to expand this plot.